# Convert datetime string with local time zone to ISO 8601

Tags: python, datetime

I am attempting to convert a DATETIME column from an Oracle database to an ISO 8601 string by doing the following:

```
from datetime import datetime

created_date_string = str(record.value['CREATION_DATE_UTC'])
created_date = datetime.strptime(created_date_string, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")
created_date_iso = created_date.isoformat()
```

The value of `created_date_string` is `"Mon Sep 09 06:25:18 EDT 2019"`. When running this code I get the following exception:

```
ValueError: time data 'Mon Sep 09 06:25:18 EDT 2019' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'
```

If I remove the timezone "EDT" from the original string and remove "%Z" from the format, it works fine. How can I build an ISO string that will keep the time zone information? I have no control over the format of the date format coming from the Oracle system. The ISO string needs to be generated to insert into an Elasticsearch index.

Comment: @MayankPorwal: OP wants to convert *to* ISO-8601, not *from* it.

Comment: @Sri I know... that's why I'm putting the question here. I'm unable to convert without the timezone info and looking for another way.

Comment: So if you had a way to identify *just* the timezone, you'd be all set?

Comment: @ScottHunter EDT is 4 hours behind UTC (-04:00). I'm new to Python, but I figured strptime would be able to convert that to the necessary date object while maintaining the time zone specified, but it looks like it can't. Looking for another way to make this happen. The end result of this should be "2019-09-06T10:25:18.000-04:00"

Comment: I'm stuck using Python 2.7 in a corporate environment... so no luck at new features of Python 3.

Comment: So break it up into: 1) split the timezone from the rest of the string, 2) identify the UTC offset from the timezone, 3) parse the rest of the string as you described, 4) adjust for the timezone

Comment: @ScottHunter there has to be an easier way... that's going to  take dozens of lines of code. I have done this exact thing in .Net and in JavaScript with a single line.

Comment: Your code works fine for me (MacOSX Python 2.7.16), though I (obviously) have to hard-code the value for `created_date_string`.

Comment: Not sure how it's working for you. I can't get it working in any environment. See repl.it link for code.. you can see the error there.

[link](https://repl.it/repls/PunyClassicTrials)

Comment: Just realized that link is for Python 3.8. Same thing happens in 2.7 HERE: [link](https://repl.it/repls/UnawareAptGlitch)

Comment: Neither string matches your question in the 2.7 link.

Comment: Sorry I was messing around with it and it auto-updates. Check again.